# VB Excel - To find matches

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a macro to do the follow:
In an Excel table

```
A B C
------
a
b
c
d
```

I will paste a data in column `C` for instance

```
A B C
------
a   b
b   b
c   f
d
```

The result I'm looking for is to find number of matches in `A` and `B` and if there is not match to add element to column `A` as follow:

```
A B C
-----
a   b
b 2 b
c   f
d
f 1
```

Comment: Which is the size of data array, or simply - how many elements in column A?

Answer (score 0):

This subroutine will count the # of matching items in Column C and print the result in Column B.

```
Sub MatchColumnAtoColumnC()
Dim rngA as Range
Dim rngC as Range
Dim cl as Range

Set rngA = Range("A1",Range("A1").End(Xldown))
Set rngC = rngA.Offset(0,2)

For Each cl in rngA
    cl.Offset(0,1).Value = CountIf(cl,rngC)
Next

End Sub
```